# Помогите решить задание

Tags: python

Заполнить вводом с клавиатуры численный список за исключением последнего элемента, вывести его на экран.

Запросить еще одно значение и его позицию в в списке.

Вставить указанное число в заданную позицию, подвинув элементы после него.

Вот что я пробовал:

```
a = [] 

enter = input("Введите численный список: ").split() 
readylist = a + enter 

enter2 = input("Введите последнее не численное значение: ").split() 
ready = readylist + enter2 in ready 

print(ready)
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Алгоритм ты описал - перепиши его на питоне

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста, что вы пробовали.

Comment: a = []

enter = input("Введите численный список:").split()

readylist = a + enter

enter2 = input("Введите последнее не численое значение:").split()
ready = readylist + enter2


in ready


print(ready)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [int(x) for x in input("Введите список: ").split()]
i,x = map(int, input("Введите позицию и число: ").split())
print(a[:i:] + [x] + a[i::])
```

```
Введите список: 1 2 3 4 5
Введите позицию и число: 3 0
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Заполнить вводом с клавиатуры численный список `за исключением последнего элемента`

Comment: @S.Nick, я предполагаю, что задание было изначально не под питон и в этой фразе имеется в виду, что в языках, где у массивов длина задаётся раз и навсегда, надо сразу зарезервировать на 1 элемент больше, чтобы потом было, куда двигать. Впрочем, я сдвиг не сделал - у меня новый список получается...